Are question about rhythm games on topic?
I mean like Pump It Up, Dance Dance Revolution, Maimai, Chunithm and others.
Others played in PC or mobile seems to be on-topic, but I'm not sure about those.
Already checked this question but it seems the OP is asking more about "street fighter" arcade games.

Yes. Questions about rhythm games are on-topic.

In particular, there is already a [dance-dance-revolution] tag, with 10 questions so far.
